# Is Pycharm not finding PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I get an error "No module named PIL" when I use this code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```

I have uninstalled and installed Pillow already, but the error still pops up.
Maybe Pycharm just isn't finding PIL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I needed to uninstall Pillow, in PyCharm press Ctrl+Alt+S, and add Pillow as a package, not PIL.